# Как задать значение css-свойству из props компонента React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scss, jsx

Задача - необходимо присваивать компоненту React css-класс, в котором значение конкретного свойства будет равным значению передаваемому в `props`. Пример для наглядности:

```
<FlexBox
    flexGrow="1"
>
    helloWorld
<FlexBox/>
```

На выходе получаем

```
<div class="flex-grow">helloWorld</div>

.flex-grow {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Возможно ли это не прибегая к использованию inline-стилей, используя SASS? Необходимо именно назначение конкретному свойству к конкретном css-классе значения передаваемого в `props`. 
Styled components и CSS Modules, как я понял, не мой вариант. Может существуют другие средства которые помогут реализовать данную идею? Возможно существует какой то способ связать переменную в SASS-миксине со значением `flexGrow` из `props`?

Comment: _не прибегая к использованию inline-стилей_ скорей всего только ими и получится, через `<div style={{flexGrow: this.props.flexGrow}}>helloWorld</div>`

Comment: @DmitryKozlov к сожалению, inline-стили не вариант. Будем искать способы.

Answer (score 1):

предлагаю такой вариант:

```
import classnames from 'classnames';

const FlexBox = ({ props }) => {
  const classesToApply = classNames({
    'flex-grow': props.flexGrow,
    'test-class': props.testClass
    // тут мапим нужные классы и пропсы
  });

  return <ChildComponent className={classesToApply}>Hello world!</ChildComponent>
}

const ChildComponent = ({ props }) => (
  <div className={props.className}>
    {props.children}
  </div>
);
```

Обращаю внимание, что значение пропсы flexGrow будет приводится к булеву типу (т.е. независимо от того будет там 1 или 2 -> на выходе мы получим класс flex-grow.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Ваш вариант похож на тот, который используется сейчас, то есть можно поставить значению flex-grow либо 0 либо 1, то же самое и с flex-shrink. Но я пытаюсь решить задачу именно так, чтобы в значение свойства шла цифра, указанная в props. Есть конечно вариант прописать кучу классов для n-ого количества значений, и через массив объектов, каждый из которых будет содержать значение props, по которому производить поиск и имя класса который присваивать при совпадении, добавлять необходимый класс, но я надеюсь что удастся найти более изящное решение.